# NodeJS 1614.2 v8.promiseHooks

Tags: node.js, v8

I am trying to import promiseHooks from v8, but could not find at all.
Based on nodeJs API documentation it should be added in v16.14.0.

How can I import it?

```
$ node --version
v16.14.2
```

My code :

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { promiseHooks } from 'v8';

function after(){console.trace()}

promiseHooks.onAfter(after)

fetch('http://httpbin.org/get')
    .then(response => console.log('Print response'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Are you talking about [AsyncHooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) in nodejs which supports promise lifetime events too?  Many more articles [here](https://medium.com/nmc-techblog/the-power-of-async-hooks-in-node-js-8a2a84238acb) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+promise+hooks).

Comment: Thank you. I would like to use [promise-hooks](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/v8.html#promise-hooks)
Looks like my IDE needs to configure correctly, I need to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that it is working, just my IDE could not find the export.
I am using IntelliJ and it tries to import from node/v8.d.ts instead of v8.js.